# Referencing environment variables in elastic beanstalk parameters

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.1, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know how to set environment parameters inside Elastic Beanstalk by console or option settings, but I can't give with how to set an option value from other environment variable. For example:

```
RDS_HOSTNAME = "myhostname" 
PGHOST = RDSHOSTNAME
```

A workarround I found is to set an "export PGHOST = $RDS_HOSTNAME" in the container commands:

```
container_commands:   
  01_set_variables:
    command: "export PGHOST = $RDS_HOSTNAME"
```

but I would like if there is possible to set directly in option settings, like other environment variable.

**UPDATE**
Setting referenced variable with $ and brackets it works. Example:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: PGHOST
    value: ${RDS_HOSTNAME}
```